# XSLT - create a variable which should contain unique and sorted data

Tags: sorting, xslt, unique

I'm using XSLT 2.0 and Apache FOP for the XSLT transformation.

My task is to create a variable which will contain the unique and sorted category names from the following XML structure:

```
<equipment>
    <E0132>
        <category>1. First Aid</category>
        <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</description>
    </E0132>
    <E0133>
        <category>1. First Aid</category>
        <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</description>
    </E0133>
    <E4122>
        <category>3. Fire safety</category>
        <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</description>
    </E4122>
    <E4182>
        <category>3. Fire safety</category>
        <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</description>
    </E4182>
    <E4622>
        <category>2. Access control</category>
        <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</description>
    </E4622>
    <E5225>
        <category>4. Recognition</category>
        <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</description>
    </E5225>
</equipment>
```

The XSL code that I have so far is this:

```
<xsl:variable name="equipment">
    <xsl:for-each select="//equipment/node()/category">
        <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending" />

        <xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(.)"/>               
    </xsl:for-each>        
</xsl:variable>
```

It solves the sorting part, but it seems that the `distinct-values()` function does not work, I have duplicated values.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `distinct-values` around your select expression

```
<xsl:for-each select="distinct-values(//equipment/node()/category)">
    <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending" />
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>               
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Hello, Tim. That's for the answer. One more question though: as I understand it, now the `$equipment` variable will only have the text from within each `category` node. Is it possible to preserve the nodes as well?

Comment: `distinct-values` returns atomic values. You should look into `xsl:for-each-group` if you wish to preserve nodes.

Comment: Can you help me with an example?

I tried with this code, but it's not what I expected:
`<xsl:variable name="equipment">
 <xsl:for-each-group select="//equipment/node()" group-by="category">
  <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending" />
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>              
 </xsl:for-each-group>        
</xsl:variable>`

Comment: I would suggest asking a whole new question about this. It is hard to follow code in comments. Thanks!

Comment: What if I edit the original question and then you add a separate answer?

Comment: This particular question may serve as a reference to other users out there, so it is best to leave it as it is. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, going to create a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Tim, if you can help with the new question, the link is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50737725/xsl-store-unique-and-sorted-data-in-a-variable)