# XSL - store unique and sorted data in a variable

Tags: sorting, xslt, grouping, unique

Using XSLT 2.0 and Apache FOP I want to be able to create a new variable, have unique and sorted values inside it by `category` but preserve the nodes. So the new variable should have the following nodes:

```
<category>1. First Aid</category>
<category>2. Access control</category>
<category>3. Fire safety</category>
<category>4. Recognition</category>
```

The input XML is the following:

```
<equipment>
    <E0132>
        <category>1. First Aid</category>
        <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</description>
    </E0132>
    <E0133>
        <category>1. First Aid</category>
        <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</description>
    </E0133>
    <E4122>
        <category>3. Fire safety</category>
        <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</description>
    </E4122>
    <E4182>
        <category>3. Fire safety</category>
        <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</description>
    </E4182>
    <E4622>
        <category>2. Access control</category>
        <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</description>
    </E4622>
    <E5225>
        <category>4. Recognition</category>
        <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</description>
    </E5225>
</equipment>
```

In regard to the XSL, this is what I have so far:

```
<xsl:variable name="equipment">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//equipment/node()" group-by="category">
        <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending" />
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>              
    </xsl:for-each-group>        
</xsl:variable>
```

But it's not working as expected. It doesn't contain the `category` nodes as I would like to and I don't know how to integrate `distinct-values()` XSL function here in order to achieve unicity.

Comment: You should (probably) use `xsl:copy-of` and not `xsl:value-of`. However, depending on what problem you are actually trying to solve, maybe you don't need variables at all. If you are just trying to create some sort of "lookup" perhaps `xsl:key` can be your friend here? It would help you showed the output you expect, and explain the actual logic you are trying to implement here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `current-grouping-key()` function to store the values. Below is the updated variable declaration.

```
<xsl:variable name="equipment">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="//equipment/*/category" group-by=".">
        <xsl:sort select="." order="ascending" />
        <category>
            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
        </category>              
    </xsl:for-each-group>   
</xsl:variable>
```

To check the variable contents

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$equipment" />
```

gives output as

```
<category>1. First Aid</category>
<category>2. Access control</category>
<category>3. Fire safety</category>
<category>4. Recognition</category>
```

EDIT: To print the variable values within a loop, try the below

```
<!-- print variable values -->
<xsl:for-each select="$equipment/category" >
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Output

```
1. First Aid
2. Access control
3. Fire safety
4. Recognition
```

Comment: But I need to have that output stored in a variable which I then later use for getting and displaying the `description` for each category.

Comment: Are you planning to store a `node-set()` in a variable or just the values in the variable which you can later loop through?

Comment: My XSL knowledge is pretty limited, so I believe I need a `node-set()`. And the values need to be unique.

Comment: I have updated the answer to store the `node-set()` in a variable and then check the variable contents.

Comment: I implemented your solution, but the problem is that if I run a for-each on `$equipment` I get a single row with all the names, like all of them have been concatenated there instead of having a row for each name:

`<xsl:for-each select="$equipment">   
 <xsl:variable name="category" select="category"/>
 <fo:block>
  <xsl:text>- </xsl:text> <xsl:value-of select="$category" />
 </fo:block>
</xsl:for-each>`

Comment: I have edited the answer to print the variable values in a loop.

Comment: I managed to make it work. The loop should have been on `$equipment/category`.

Comment: One more question though: does this have an impact on the original //equipment node? Does it alter its structure? I'm asking because if later in the code I run a for-each on `//equipment/node()[category = $group]/description` where `$group` is a variable that holds a value from `$equipment/category` and I get no data, like the `description` node is not there.